# Receiving 200 response status in spring interceptor for an actual 500 or 403 response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I wrote a spring HandlerInterceptor to log my performance loggers for all my RestControllers.

afterCompletion() method receives HttpServletResponse object. When I print response.getStatus() its printing 200 even when Access is denied or when there is an internal server error.

How do I get the proper error response. Looks like for my use case I can use this HandlerInterceptor only for successfully processed requests. If need to log all kind of request and push metrics to DB and see on grafana, how do I do it in Spring.

Comment: Do you have any exception resolver? please share your exception resolver.

Comment: I don’t have exception resolver.